# How can I pass a Model/Model-name to a method in (Ruby/Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method that generates a random string for an entry in a particular DB table. I need that random string to be unique in that table.

To do that, I am using the following snippet:

```
@mymodel = MyModel.find_by_random_string(random_string)
if !@mymodel.nil?
   . . . 
else
   . . . 
end
```

My issue is that I would like to generalize this method for use in multiple tables. So, obviously, I can't hardcode 'MyModel' into it. But I don't know how to pass in a model.

How can I do this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you give a use case/example?

Comment: Simply replace `MyModel` with `self.class`

Comment: This worked, real simple! Tnx!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can generate unique random strings for random classes like this:

```
class RandomStringGenerator
  def self.generate_random_string_for(klass)
    loop do
      random_string = SecureRandom.hex(5)[0..8].upcase
      break random_string unless klass.exists?(random_string: random_string)
    end
  end
end

RandomStringGenerator.generate_random_string_for(MyModel) # => "679086C37"
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. 2 Q's. 1-Is SecureRandom built into Rails? 2-The letters would be limited to 'F', is that correct? (I am looking at the 'hex', thing...)

Comment: @Jo.P SecureRandom is a standard Ruby library. Yes, letters would be limited to f, this is just an example, you can generate your strings in a different way. Note: I moved this in separate class, because in this way your code would be DRY. You don't need to add/maintain same logic in every class.